# Creating Branching Python Script, Based on Whether Feature Classes Exists or Not?

Tags: arcpy, modelbuilder

What I would like to do is create a script that checks the existence of a feature class and, depending whether it does or not does, skip to different process. This would need to be implemented in Modelbuilder so if there is a tool I have not utilized (instead of a script), point me in the right direction!

I am a complete noob when it comes to Python, so the simpler the better!

Comment: here's a good place to start http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00210000000q000000

Comment: Essentially, what I would like to do is create a Python script that branches (if the feature dataset exists, to go straight to a Select by Location process and if it doesn't to complete the conversion from a shapefile to geodatabase).

I am a complete noob to Python so please make it simple for me!

Comment: ah, that's a bit different, it would be good if you could update the question to include your desire for a python script.  what you're asking for is not too difficult, but the more details the better.

Comment: So you want to prepare it in Model Builder and then export it to a script? Or is a script sufficient? And what exatly do you mean by checking if a file exists? Will you apply the sript to a folder and see if anything is in it first of all? Because any other way, you would provide a file, and in that case it would exist anyways.

Answer (score 4):

There is an Esri blog post that describes the technique for doing this in detail called [If you are stuck at "if" – Part 1](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/06/06/modelbuilderifthenelse1/):

> Part 1 – Gives examples of quick and dirty ways of using the Calculate
>   Value tool to create branches using if statements in a model.

In your case you want to check for the existence of a feature class rather than a product license so I would use this as the code for your `Feature Class exists Python script tool`:

Expression

```
x("%FCToCheck%")
```

Code Block

```
def x(FCToCheck):
import arcpy
if arcpy.Exists(FCToCheck):
    return "true"
else:
    return "false"
```

and this as the code for your `Feature Class does not exist Python script tool`:

Expression;

```
x("%ProductToCheck%")
```

Code Block

```
def x(FCToCheck):
import arcpy
if arcpy.Exists(FCToCheck):
    return "false"
else:
    return "true"
```

Personally, I far prefer to implement such branching using pure Python/ArcPy rather than having ModelBuilder in the mix.